# Hitting Alt doesn't bring up the HUD

Tags: unity, 13.04, hud

I just noticed that the HUD appears to be gone. I updated to 13.04 recently and tapping <kbd>Alt</kbd> doesn't do anything. The <kbd>Alt</kbd> (tap) shortcut is even gone from the cheat sheet that appears when I hold <kbd>Super</kbd>.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try System Settings - Keyboard - Shortcuts - Launchers. Do you see 'Key to show the HUD'? It should be the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Comment: Alt+L? (filler filler)

Comment: aha, yup. that did it, thanks. I guess I panicked -- I didn't know the cheat sheet was programmatically generated from your existing settings; the shortcut must've just gotten wiped somehow.

Comment: No, 'ALT L'. (the left ALT-key). That's how it displays. But if I really hit that key it displays as 'Mod2+ Alt L'.

Comment: the Mod2 thing is an artifact of how the keyboard shortcut panel reacts to numlock for some reason